# Android vibrator

Tags: java, android, vibration

I'm using AIDE on Android and I can't get it to vibrate.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
import android.os.*;

Vibrator.vibrate((long)1000);
```

It says(on the .vibrate line) that "There is no such reference available here." When I check the definitions inside the app, there's Vibrator.vibrate right there.

What's wrong here? It must be something simple, but the solution's not on the web or anywhere else.

Comment: ;) it wasn't deliberate

Comment: @JosefE. Would you prefer "How to make an Android vibrate?" :)

Answer (score 5):

> What's wrong here?

`vibrate()` is not a static method. You cannot call `vibrate()` on the `Vibrator` class. You need to call `vibrate()` on an *instance* of the `Vibrator` class. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html):

> To obtain an instance of the system vibrator, call getSystemService(String) with VIBRATOR_SERVICE as the argument.

You will also need to request the `VIBRATE` permission in your manifest, and run the code on a device that has a vibration motor.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get an actual instance of the class from the system, you can't call the method like this.
Given you are inside of an Activity:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(1000);
```

Also, ensure you have the corresponding permission set in your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes sense. I was trying to create an instance of the class Vibrator the usual way instead of putting a Vibrator cast on the systemservice of vibrator.